# Login with custom authentication

Tags: symfony

I want a login with a custom field to authenticate users into the platform.
The point is to check a field 'pw_expires_at' to `\DateTime('now')`, to log the user.

Here's what I did so far:

In the controller:

```
$user->setPassword(
    $passwordEncoder->encodePassword(
    $user,    
    $mdp)
);

$user->setPwExpiresAt(new \DateTime("now + 1 minute"));

$entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$entityManager->persist($user);
$entityManager->flush();
```

In the Authenticator:

```
public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)
{
    $valid = false;
    $validDate = $this->checkDate($credentials, $user);
    $validPassword = $this->passwordEncoder->isPasswordValid($user, $credentials['password']);

    if($validDate && $validPassword) {
        $valid = true;
    }

    return $valid;

}

/**
 * @return bool
 */
public function checkDate($credentials, UserInterface $user){

    $now = new \DateTime('now');
    $pwdate = new \DateTime();

    $pwdate = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Users::class)->findOneBy([
        'email' => $credentials['email']
    ]);

    if ($pwdate > $now) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I also added the new function `checkDate()` in the AuthenticatorInterface.php.

The problem is : I can log in at anytime.

Comment: your line `$pwdate = $this->entityManager ...` doesn't make any sense at all. the result object is a User, not a datetime. then apparently comparing a user to a datetime is always false (whatever that means) so your checkdate always returns true. I guess you're missing a `->getPwExpiresAt()` call or something. also your logic is wrong, checkdate should be false, when $now > $pwdate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing (`>`) a user object `repository->findBy(...)` which returns a `Users::class` with a `DateTime` object `$now = new \DateTime();`.

Also the `$user` object entityManager reponse is most likely the same object returned by your `getUsername` function (the one you pass as an argument in this function) and thus can be skipped? If it is a DTO that does not contain this expired value then add it back in.
Also you are not using the credentials for anything anymore then so removed it as well.

I would change this to something like:

```
public function checkDate(UserInterface $user) {
    $now = new \DateTime();

    $pwdate = $user->getPwExpiresAt();

    // we dont need the if/else as this ($pwdate > $now)
    // is an expression and will already return true/false;
    return $pwdate > $now; 
}
```

Some more suggestions:

- You might want to reconsider renaming the function to something more expressive like `$this->hasAuthenticationExpired($user)` this should give a clear indication of what the function is doing other than "checking a date (for what?!)" without reading through the function.
- You can move this function to the user object like
  `public function hasExpired() { return $this->getPwExpiresAt() && new \DateTime() > $this->getPwExpiresAt(); }`
  and just call `if (!$user->hasExpired()) {` which is actually a preferred way for many people as this can be easily reused and accessed whenever handling the user object anywhere.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Indeed, the logic was wrong. I still have a lot to learn... Thanks also for giving me tips to have a clearer code ! :)